# Media Query for phonegap app on Nokia Lumia

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, media-queries

I am developing app for Nokia Lumia 620. I know a bit about media queries of ios phonegap app but not get how to deal with media queries for Nokia Lumia 620, 900 and 920 in the same css. So please tell me how can I write media query for it.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found a way to do that. I am using like this -

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {  
@-ms-viewport  
{ 
  width: 480px; 
}
```